# sucess message displaying even after the page gets refresh

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a JSP page which displays a success message on successful inserted of an item.

However, if the page is refreshed, I want the message to not be displayed. I tried all I could do but it just doesn't happen.

My servlet code is :

```
request.setAttribute("profilestrength", 
   "<b>Your Profile Strength HasBeen Saved");
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("profile.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

In jsp I am using this method to get display the message:

```
<p style="color:green">${profilestrength}</p>
```

Comment: Page refresh = servlet (or JSP) is executed. Handle the situation in the servlet/jsp code. Or give us more code to understand your intention.

Comment: After a successful POST, you should not forward, but redirect. Otherwise, the refresh will send the POST again. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get. Once done, save your message in the session before redirecting, and remove it from the session as soon as it has been displayed.

Comment: please give me a code